# Relating induction proof to Cantor's Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would a proof by induction to show that $n < 2^n$ for all $n \in ℤ$ be related to showing Cantor's Theorem for finite sets?

I have the proof completed however I don't quite see the relation between the two. I understand that Cantor's Theorem states that the power set of any given set will have a greater cardinality than that of the given set.

All explanations are much appreciated thank you.

Comment: It's a combinatorial fact the for a set of $n$ elements, its power set has $2^n$ elements.

Comment: Appreciate it! I really was not using my head for this haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a finite set $S$ has cardinality $n,$ what is the cardinality of the power set of $S$?

Comment: Oh, shoot I can't believe I didn't realize this, I must have been thinking of something else. Thank you so much!